# run: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

[I am trying to store user details into database for my project and even I tried all the solutions provided on the forums, but nothing worked and i am using phpmyadmin and mysqlserver , pls anyone help me to overcome the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgDI3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the password that you have set for mysql.
Your connection url should look like this.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_Database","root","mysql_password");
```

Comment: I have forgot what i have given for username and password, how to find out the username and password that I have given?

Comment: Password reset!

Comment: You can reconfigure in MySQL Server Instance Config Wizard. Just search it from start menu.

Comment: Thank you so much Zohaib and Nic3500 :-) Igot that error cleared.

Comment: no i didnt get  MySQL Server Instance Config Wizard  option in start menu Zohaib

Comment: database table is not getting inserted in  mysql command line client ,after running program successfully ,and showing no errors

Comment: Show me your query